# R: How to pass two filepaths as parameters to a function?

Tags: r, function, file

I'm trying to pass two file paths as parameters to a function. But it's not accepting the inputs. Here's what I'm doing:

```
partition<-function(d1,p2){

     d1<-read.table(file = d1, fill = TRUE)
     p2<-read.table(file = p2, fill = TRUE) 

}
```

and while calling the function:

```
partition("samcopy.txt","partcopy.txt")
```

The .txt is not being read by the variables inside the function. How to make the variables read the table?

Comment: Are you receiving an an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: I'm not receiving any error. It's just not reading the path that I've given as input.

Comment: What is letting you know it's not reading the path? Is your working directory at the location of those files?

Comment: You should return valued from the function like return(list(d1,p2))

Comment: I'm checking the variables inside the function. They are not changing. Is this the right way to check whether the given input is being read? Yes working directory is at the location of those files.

Comment: @cccmir I was not returning anything. is this the reason, it was not accepting the input?

Comment: The files were being read and stored as variables in the function, but as soon as the function exits, the values disappear. Usually your function should return the values you are interested in keeping. That's a much safer strategy than creating functions that have side-effects like modifying the global environment which is what the answer suggesting `<<-` is doing.

Comment: @Dungeoun MrFlick wrote, variable are created in the function environment and not in the global environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AidanGawronSki's  approach works, but from a programming standpoint should be avoided!  Here is a more traditional answer to your problem.

```
partition<-function(d1,p2){
     a <- read.table(file = d1, fill = TRUE)
     b <- read.table(file = p2, fill = TRUE) 
     res <- list(a,b)
     names(res) <- c(d1,p2)
     res
}
```

To understand why the above approach is "better", it is important to understand what environments are and more generally the R scoping rules.  Environments are essentially your workspace.  For example, when you first open R and begin assigning objects, these objects are stored within the Global Environment. Another example of an environment is when you call a function, the function creates it own environment comprised of any parameters you have passed to the function.  By doing this R ensures that when you call a function, it has no "side effects" or said another way it does not affect the global environment.

Let me show you an example.  Imagine you begin an R session, and assign `d1 <- 1` in your Global Environment.  You're going to want to use `d1` later on in your analysis and it would be a shame if it changed without you knowing it, right?

If you utilize AidanGawronSki's approach when you call

```
partition<-function(d1,p2){
 d1 <<- read.table(file = d1, fill = TRUE)
}
```

The `d1` in your Global Environment will change to be `read.table(file = d1, fill = TRUE)`.  This is very very dangerous!  A object you previously assigned to be one thing is now another thing and you are not even warned of this change.

The same problem, however, will never occur with the approach I have proposed.  I strongly recommend you get in the habit of using this approach!  If you don't any function can change things in your Global Environment without you knowing.

For more info read [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html), [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) or just google something like "functions with no side effects"

FYI there are also several other problems with your code.  First you need to tell your function what to return.  All you did is call a function, assign stuff to the local environment and then close the function.  Functions will always return the last line (as long as it is not an assignment).  This is why in my example, I put `res` as the last line of the function.  Also you are not correctly assigning your object.  You pass a string like `d1 <- "text.txt"`, to your function and then ask your function to do the following, `"text.txt" <- read.table("text.txt",...)`.  That simply does not make sense.  You need to assign the output from `read.table` to an object.  In my example, I assign them to `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

use the super assignment operator <<-

```
partition<-function(d1,p2){
     d1 <<- read.table(file = d1, fill = TRUE)
     p2 <<- read.table(file = p2, fill = TRUE) 
}
```